# Google Data Studio displays "null" – how to set the field value?

Tags: null, field, looker-studio

I am new to Google Data Studio. I think I have an issue, with turning dimensions into metrics or with correct assignement of values. This is because a colulmn which should display numbers just displays the string „null“.

This is how it should look. (Example from book)
[image: It should look like this with "real" numbers in the transaction amount column]

But this is how it looks:

[image: As you can see, transaction number is "0". And in the Data Control Panel on the right, "Balance" and "Transaction Amount" is a dimension (green) and not a metric – in the "Availabe Fields" panel]

The column „Transaction Number“ is „null“.

I think sth. went wrong with the data source. It’s an CSV. Like this:
[image: This is the data-strcuture in the csv]

And within Data Studio I transformed some of the field values and the Aggregation.

[image: I don't get the fields like in the book. So for example "Balance" is a dimension – and not a metric. But I have the some type as in the book]

I did not get Transaction amount blue colored, like it should be, (see example from book below) And also „balance“ is a not blue (metric.)
[image]

I think, this leads to displaying transaction amount column to „null“. But I can’t turn these values into metrics from within the data control panel.

But maybe I am wrong. **So what need Datas Studio to display actual values and not null?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Summary

The number columns (`Transaction Amount` and `Balance`) are currently treated as **Text** columns in Google Sheets (one indication is the left alignment of the respective values, which is the default for **Plain Text** columns in Google Sheets), thus the symbols `$` and `,` are part of the value thus `$200,000.00` is treated a literal and is displayed as a **Text** field when creating the Google Data Studio Data Source.

One approach is to change the formatting in Google Sheets (or remove the respective characters `$` and `,`); the below looks at a suggestion within Google Data Studio by extracting the numbers from the field, using three steps:

## 1) Text

At the [Data Source](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6300774), ensure that both the `Transaction Amount` and `Balance` fields are set to **Text** fields.

A GIF to elaborate:

[image]

## 2) Calculated Fields

At the Data Source, create the two [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7067058) [Calculated Fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below and set the semantic type to `Currency (USD)`:

**2.1) `Transaction Amount`**

```
CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(Transaction Amount, "\\$", ""), ",", "") AS NUMBER )
```

**2.2) `Balance`**

```
CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(Balance, "\\$", ""), ",", "") AS NUMBER )
```

**2.3) Hide**
Hide the original Text fields for `Transaction Amount` and `Balance`

GIF to visualise the above:

[image]

## 3) Metrics

Add the Newly created `Transaction Amount` and `Balance` Currency Fields into the required chart, such as **Metrics** in a [Table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044).

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/db0ab65d-6942-454c-a8e9-05775683b4df) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I am late in the game, and perhaps I am not actually answering your question, but there is actually a setting where you can set how to display, or not to display, Null.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunatly this does not OP's question, however it does point out correctly how to handle `null` values if you want them to not show up. Based on the title of the question, this might actually be what people look for, such as me. Thanks.